# Native unit test code coverage for c++ static lib not detected

Tags: c++, visual-studio, code-coverage

I have a static lib for which I have written Native Unit tests . I have followed the link and done all steps in https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/cpp-testing-in-visual-studio/

But when I run the Code coverage for tests . It doesnt show the code coverage for the lib at all. I have configured Linker > Debugging > Generate Debug Info =/DEBUG:FULL for unit test project and also Linker-> Advanced->Profile = Yes(Profile).

Can anyone please help me with this I m not able to understand what am I missing.

Comment: I assume you use Visual Studio? So I've added that as a tag.

Comment: This worked actually lib file is not listed separately in the coverage results. Coverage for cpp files are shown under the Unit test dll itself . Its quite confusing . In c# its listed separate .anyways it was showing the results.